# Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix geth.ipc: connect: connection refused

Tags: ethereum

I'm trying to run Ethereum node on my own server. When I try to access the geth node, by running the command `/blockchain_nodes/node1# geth attach geth.ipc`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix geth.ipc: connect: connection refused
```

Expected result should open me the Geth JavaScript console.

Comment: Did you have any luck? I have the same error.